# Convert character text to date format

Tags: r, datetime

I have character text in the following format

```
Jan 10, 09:56
```

I need to convert it to date format like below

```
01/10/2018 09:56
```

How to do that?

Comment: `strptime(paste("2018", x), "%Y %b %d, %H:%M")`

Comment: It can be done by parsing text, but want to check if there is any inbuild function which can help

Comment: How do you expect R to understand year without explicitly mentioning it?

Comment: @RonakShah As I will be on today's date,  I can add it by  `year(Sys.Date())` . Getting year is not a problem, parsing the text is my problem. Anyhow tqs for your quick solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work for you?

```
foo <- "Jan 10, 09:56" 
bar <- strptime(paste("2018", foo), "%Y %b %d, %H:%M")
format(bar, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
#> [1] "01/10/2018 09:56"
```